# file handling in c : can not read proper in table format data

Tags: c, file-handling

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
   clrscr();
   FILE *fin;

   fin=fopen("data.txt","r");

   if(fin==NULL)
   {
    printf("can not open input fil");
    return 0;
   }

   long data[2];

   while(!feof(fin))
   {
       fscanf(fin,"%ld %ld",&data[0],&data[1]);
       printf("\n%ld %ld",data[0],data[1]);
   }
   fclose(fin);
   return;
   }
```

above is my c code for reading a table from a file.In that ..last value is printing 2 times !!!

```
data.txt
1   34
2   24
3   45
4   56
5   67
```

but I can not get proper values with broken table like below...How can I resolve it ? (here It should work where it does not find any value it should return "null space" or zero ..but not the next value..)

```
data.txt
1   34
2   
3   45
4   
5   67
```

as well as
    data.txt

```
1 34
  57
3 45
4   
5 34
```

Answer (score 2):

> above is my c code for reading a table from a file.In that ..last value is printing 2 times !!!

The last value is printing two times due to the structure of the file reading loop. The `eof()` flag is not set until an attempt is made to read past the end of the file. When `fscanf()` reads the last two `long`s from the last line of the file `eof()` is not yet set but the next call to `fscanf()` fails and sets `eof()` but the result of `fscanf()` is not queried immediately, resulting the use of the previously extracted `long`s: check the result of all read operations immediately.

---

A possible solution is to read a line at a time, using [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), and then use [`sscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to extract the `long` value(s) from the read line. If `fscanf()` is used, it would read past the new-line character to locate the second requested `long`, which is not the desired behaviour.

For example:

```
char line[1024];
while (fgets(line, 1024, fin))
{
    /* Assign appropriate default values.
       sscanf() does not modify its arguments
       for which it has no value to assign.
       So if 'line' has a single long value
       data[1] will be zero. */
    long data[2] = { 0, 0 };

    /* You can use 'result' if you require to take particular
       action if it reads only 1, or 0, items. */
    int result = sscanf(line, "%ld %ld", &data[0], &data[1]);

    printf("\n%ld %ld",data[0],data[1]);
}
```

---

(*in response to question update*) To differentiate between lines where second value is missing:

> 2

and lines where first value is missing:

> 57

a valid range (or some other criteria) is required to determine which value (the first or second) was missing from the line:

```
int result = sscanf(line, "%ld %ld", &data[0], &data[1]);
if (1 == result)
{
    if (data[0] >= 1 && data[0] <= 9)
    {
        printf("\n%ld 0", data[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        /* Read value was the second value. */
        printf("\n%ld %ld", ++last_first_value, data[0]);
    }
}
```

where `last_first_value` is a `long` that stores the current value of the first value (either the last successfully read first value or computed from the last successfully read first value).

Comment: the output is something like...

1   34
2   34
3   45
4   45
5   67

and in second case :
1   34
57  34
3   45
4   45
5   67 (odd numers are 1st column and even are second)

Comment: still facing problems where the "FIRST" value is missing...It is taking the second one as a FIRST..and gives 0 to second one... and as it is just example table... In real one the data is about 5-7000 lines,may be the column number also increase.

Comment: That code update (for checking first value missing) is wrong.  `sscanf` will skip past any whitespace.  You need to check characters on the line itself: `if (line[0] >= '1' && line[0] <= '9')`.  A better way would be to check `if (!isspace(line[0]))`.  I would have also put the correct numbers back into the `data` array if I was going to use them for anything.

Comment: @paddy, there is no leading whitespace if the second value is present. The check for first character being a space helps in no way at all.

Comment: The example broken file contains leading whitespace when the first value is missing.  I don't see where it has been said otherwise.

Comment: @paddy, I don't see where it says it has and the example output shows no leading whitespace.

Comment: @paddy- if there are 2 column only and the first on is missing  than I can check  "isspace" but what if there are 3 columns and value in second column is missing !!!

Comment: @hmjd It doesn't *say* that it does...  It just *is* there.  In the question - last code section showing a `data.txt` where on the second line the first value is missing.

Comment: @user95711 If you want to detect gaps in multiple columns then it's best to detect the layout as you go.  This is easier if you have a header row, but you can do it on-the-fly.  You have to search ahead a bit, and if your data is quite sparse you may need to read the file twice (once to determine structure and once to populate).  This is only useful if the data are aligned to columns or have a set number of spaces between each value.  This is why CSV (comma-separated-value) format was invented.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(!feof(fin))
{
   fscanf(fin,"%ld %ld",&data[0],&data[1]);
   printf("\n%ld %ld",data[0],data[1]);
}
```

`feof` doesn't return `true` until after you attempt to read past the end of the file, so the loop will execute once too often.  It's better to check the return value of `fscanf` and if it doesn't match what you expect (2 in this case), *then* check for EOF.  Here's one possible restructuring:

```
int good = 1;
while (good)
{
  int itemsRead = fscanf(fin, "%ld %ld", &data[0], &data[1]);
  if (itemsRead == 2)
  {
    // process data[0] and data[1] normally
  }
  else 
  {
    good = !good;
    if (feof(fin))
      printf("Hit end of file\n");
    else if (ferror(fin))
      printf("Error during read\n");
    else
      printf("Malformed input line\n");
  }
}
```